# Why is vimdiff so slow?

Tags: ssh, putty

Whenever I'm in `vimdiff` mode, my PuTTY session slows down considerably. This is especially noticeable when I try to scroll down many lines by keeping <kbd>j</kbd> pressed.

1. Why is it so slow in comparison to regular Vim running under `vsplit`? I realize it matches across lines and color-highlights the differences, but does that account for all the speed differences?
2. What can I do about it? I would like to keep line matches across files (and color highlighting as well). What settings can I change to help speed up the performance of my `vimdiff` utility?

Comment: Simple, yet probably effective: page forward/back with ^F and ^B, respectively. Depending on your terminal mode, each `j`can force an entire screen re-paint.

Comment: @msw : That's my current workaround, but it's still quite laggy in `vimdiff` mode.

Comment: How big are the files?

Comment: @Kevin M : Not that big, 3000 lines max.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have SSH compression enabled?  This kind of scrolling and highlighting generates a whole lot of redundant terminal traffic; compression makes a huge difference over a remote link.

Comment: It could very well be the reason. How do I disable/enable SSH compression?

Comment: PuTTY's SSH panel has a "Enable compression" checkbox.

Comment: Feels much faster after enabling compression... Thanks!